# Почему не работает get_tags()?

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, почему этот код не выводит метки, установленные по умолчанию в wordpress ? Меток много, но почему-то они не выводятся

```
$tags = get_tags();
echo '<center><pre>';
var_export($tags);
echo '</pre></center>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего потому, что метки не присвоены записям.

По умолчанию параметр hide_empty установлен в true. При этом не выводятся те метки, которые не присвоены ни одной записи.